# Load content into a div using jquery and data attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

Edit: I have this installed at www.dnadigitaltv.co.uk/testing/video but I just can't get it working. I've tried different versions of jquery, edited the code, tried alternative versions but just can't make it work. Why would it work in jsfiddle but not on my website?

I have a video page which uses modX vidlister. I've got the implementation working well but what I really would like to do is when a link is clicked it loads an image and a description into relevant divs.

I've been trying to use data attributes as my site is html5 but I just can't get it to work. At the moment I have this HTML.

```
<div id="vidImage"></div>
<div id="vidDescription"></div>
<div class="listing" data-image="SampleImage" data-description="Sample Description">
  <div class="vidTitle">
    <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GDvI8UaxT9M" title="Sample   Video Title">Sample Video</a>
  </div>
  <div class="vidDescription">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum dollar site amet. Lorem Ipsum dollar site amet. Lorem Ipsum
      dollar site amet.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="vidDuration">
    <p>00:21:15</p>
  </div>
  <div class="clearBoth"></div>
</div>
```

I then have the following jQuery

```
$('div.vidTitle a').each(function(){
$(this).click(function(){
    var datasrc = $(this).parents('div.listing');
    $('#vidDescription').empty().prepend('<p>' + $(datasrc).data('description') + '</p>');
    $('#vidImage').empty().prepend('<p>' + $(datasrc).data('image') + '</p>');
    return false;
});
});
```

So the idea is that when you click on the video title it takes the content of data-image and data-description and shows it in the 2 divs (vidImage and vidDescription).

Completely lost now!

Comment: Code and markup look fine. Make sure your version of jquery supports html5 data attributes.

Comment: Do you have multiple `ID`'s that are the same?

Comment: Your code seems to work fine here http://jsfiddle.net/K2Mu2/

Comment: This is weird! I thought it must be a jquery version issue so I downloaded the latest 1.9 version and tried it with that and still it follows the link to youtube.

Comment: @wirey Thanks for your help. I quickly uploaded the code here [link]http://dnadigitaltv.co.uk/video/video.html with the latest version of jQuery and it still follows the link to youtube. Weird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to surround your jQuery so it executes after the DOM is loaded

```
jQuery(function() {
    $('div.vidTitle a').each(function(){
        $(this).click(function(){
            var datasrc = $(this).parents('div.listing');
            $('#vidDescription').empty().prepend('<p>' + $(datasrc).data('description') + '</p>');
            $('#vidImage').empty().prepend('<p>' + $(datasrc).data('image') + '</p>');
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score -2):

You'll want to do a event.preventDefault(); at the top of your click function handler, to stop it from going to the link URL, and change

```
var datasrc = $(this).parents('div.listing');
```

to

```
var datasrc = $(this).closest('div.listing');
```

and that should fix it.

Comment: parents will work.. only issue is it will find all ancestor divs with class listing

Comment: and .closest() gets the first ancestor it finds with the selector... which is what the author wants. dont know why you -1'd me for that.

Comment: even using .closest it still opens the youtube link.

Comment: event.preventDefault(); called at the top of the click event handler will stop the link from opening.

Comment: @Derek this is really strange now :( 
The event.preventDefault(); isn't working either. 
I have a full implementation at [link]http://dnadigitaltv.co.uk/testing/carp-fishing-videos.html[/link] with the exact code that is working in jsfiddle. I thought it must have been an issue with jquery not linked properly but it is :(